# Should notifications be a class in the class diagram?

Tags: uml, social-networking, modeling, diagram, class-diagram

Suppose I make a class diagram for a social network system such as facebook. Should the notifications and discussion messages have their own classes?

I do really think they should. I made a full class diagram for such a system, with notifications and messages as classes, but my teacher told me to exclude them. Now I am confused.

Comment: how can they be implemented not using a class ? What makes you thinking the answer can be 'no' ?

Comment: huh, @bruno, i made the whole class diagram with notifiactions and messages as classes, but actually my teacher told me to exclude them, this is what got me deluded, so i do believe that my teacher's advice is not worth it anymore, i just sought to find if i was right or wrong according to my first intuition , nonetheless, thank you for your reply

Comment: It depends on the level of detail you are currently designing. Your teacher might be concerned that you have added too much details. When you are at a stage where you want to plan the architecture of your system, then worrying about implementation details is too soon. It doesn't add value but distraction and extra effort targeting details that is likely going to change. When the architecture is set e.g. all components and their relations are identified, you may tackle the business entities. Of a messenger this are of course messages and notifications.

Comment: You still don't go into details here. Still don't plan details like class names or members. It's an incremental or iterative process. The most important point is that you realize that you are learning. Questioning  content or advice is very good and will help to get a very good understanding. Your teacher is there to teach you. I guess he would be very happy to know your compassion. I highly recommend to ask him why he thinks so. Tell him you are interested in his thought process that leads him to the conclusion. This is how you learn: ask questions and find answers.

Comment: Don't be arrogant to think your teacher is stupid without knowing his intentions. You may find an answer that is the opposite of what your teacher is saying. Still there are high chances that he's right. Sometimes there are no right or wrong solutions, but only opinions. You can't judge. Without knowing  details of your conversation, I think he's right. You would never put a complete facebook system into a single class diagram. You would pick components, that you have identified in a previous design process and start to get into more details _gradually_.

Comment: You can argue creating the classes and name them could be the responsibility of the developer that is implementing  them. You can argue that since this are core classes or business entities of your application their need to be planned more thoughtfully. Please ask your teacher and come back if you are still not satisfied with his idea. We can then help you to understand it or even come to the conclusion that your teacher's solution can be improved. In a discussion you are maybe able to convince him that your approach has value.

Comment: And keep in mind that most of the time when specialists are discussing a problem there is no wrong. Both know their job. One might have a different approach or a better approach. But both are right. It's all about the value or the pros and cons. Next time show your diagram, please. Only that way it is possible to evaluate it. Right now there is not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question for three reasons.

### 1. What’s the scope?

This is a core question for any work that you’ll do in your developer career: what’s the scope of the system?

- is it just core social networking functionality of one to many communication, like you had on Facebook in its early days?
- or is it a full clone of facebook, including its messaging features, but also its advertising and moderating features?

If it’s the first, you’ve done too much. If it’s the second, you forgot important parts.

**Rule 1:** Whenever there is a doubt about the scope, clarify it with your coach/manager/stakeholder before thinking you know what there is to do.

This will avoid you the frustration of doing work that is not valued. It will avoid your future customers the frustration of not getting what they’ve expected, or paying too much for something they didn’t ask for.

### 2. What’s the approach?

Whenever you model some software, there’s a purpose. Class diagrams can be used for different purposes. For example:

- is it for **analyzing** the requirements? In this domain, you will certainly have a class for `Post`, `Comment` and `UserAccounts` as well as associations between them. But you’d limit yourself to the “problem space” and not address the software solution and its UI.
- is for the **design** of the system? then it probably should address how the system will work, and give some more details about how the UI will interact with the domain object. This kind of diagram might be more detailed and show the “solution space”.

**Rule 2**: if asked to do some modeling, always clarify the purpose. In the real world, if not asked explicitly to model, clarify the agreed approach within your team.

### 3. Always clarify with the person the closest to the source

(the subtitle is already the rule).

Now, is the notification a part of the UI, because they shows posts that changed and it’s part of the solution design?  Or is it part of the domain, because the need for notification is independently of the chosen software solution? And because moreover notifications need to be tracked and delivered, and the they will work differently on mobile apps (push) and on web pages (pull)? As you see there is some room for interpretation, and depending on his/her arguments, the teacher is not necessarily wrong.

### Conclusion

As you see, it’s not right or wrong: there are a lot of nuances between the two. There are plenty of reasons that could justify your teacher’s position. I see at least two other unrelated ones:

- to adapt the time of the exercise to the average capability of your class (which would be a good sign for you)
- because the teacher already know the next questions and he/she already know that notifications will make it much more difficult (which would show that the teacher was nice).

My advice: trust your teacher, and in any case engage a discussion to understand the arguments, before jumping to quickly on unproven  conclusions.

Key takeaway: requirement analysis and modelling are a communication activity more than a technical activity. Whenever there’s a doubt, engage discussion with your stakeholders before seeking advice from strangers on the net ;-)